# Creating dynamic Form from Array of objects with binding NgModel using Iteration

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, angular2-forms

I'm creating a Dynamic form from array of objects.I can't bind the values of forms and ngModel from iteration , if iteration inside form tag doesn't bind values.The array of objects are key-pair values.Actually i want to bing ngModel with key and display key labels and key values in forms

my HTML code

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Home</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>

<form (ngSubmit)="logForm()">

<div *ngFor="let item of mainObject; let i = index ; trackBy:trackByIndex;">

        <ion-item *ngFor="let key of keys(item)">
            <ion-label floating>{{key}}</ion-label>
              <ion-input  type="text" [(ngModel)]=mainObject[i].key  name={{key}}  value={{item[key]}}></ion-input> 
        </ion-item>
</div>

 </form>

</ion-content>
```

My TS

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {


trackByIndex(index: number, obj: any): any {
    return index;
  }


mainObject:any

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

  this.mainObject  = [{ username: 'Edward', password:'edward123'}]
    console.log(this.mainObject);
  }

keys(obj){
    return Object.keys(obj);
}
```

Code and TS On STACKBLIZ

[Stackbliz code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-9h5dsd)

Comment: You can do something like this: [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-td5brc)

Here is a link to [Angular Dynamic forms](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form) for more info